# Почему сравнение идентичных строк показывает false?

Tags: java, android, if, сравнение

Почему сравнение (if) идентичных строк показывает `false`?

Код :

```
File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/папка");
ArrayList<File> files = listFilesWithSubFolders(sdPath);
for (File fl: files) {
    format = fl.getName().substring(fl.getName().lastIndexOf("."));

    if(format == ".cfg"){

    }else if (format == ".png") {
        ImageView mImageView;
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fl.getPath()));
    }

}
```

Для наглядности скрин, чтобы мне не говорили что у меня строки разные :D :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас строки разные. RTFM [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html).

Comment: if (format.equals(".png")) вот так правильно сравнивать строки

Comment: Спасибо за внимание :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что сравнивать строки нужно не при помощи `==`, а `.equals()`.

Почитайте про сравнение простых и ссылочных типов. В Вашем случае все правильно показывает, результат `false`

Comment: Спасибо, я чото тупанул, точнее забыл про `equals`. FacePalm :)

Comment: для фанатов ==  есть еще String.intern()